# How to make curl works with proxy?

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying get html page, but need proxy, for get access:

```
curl -x https://user:pass@ip:port https://google.com
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

without proxy I get google.com, for example, but not with proxy.
Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you tried : `http://user:pass@ip:port`, using http instead of https

Comment: Yes. This works. Hm...